# Trouble stripping whitespace in Shopify/Liquid

Tags: shopify, liquid, removing-whitespace

I should be able to do `<p>{%- assign x = "aa, bb, cc" -%}{{- x -}}</p>` and get `aa,bb,cc` as the output. Instead I'm getting `aa, bb, cc`.

i also tried `{% assign x = "aa, bb, cc" | strip %}` and got the same results.

Any ideas as to what's going wrong?

Comment: when use the `{- -}` use to display the content in liquid it strips the whitespace automatically. so use it without it.

Comment: @Onkar I tried that and it doesn't seem to be working. And BTW, you need both curly braces... it has to be `{{-  -}}` not `{- -}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are only removing the white spaces outside your string. Try:

```
 `{{ x | remove:" "}}`
```

or for removing only the space next to the coma

```
 {{ x | replace: "," , " "}}
```

:)

Comment: or right... my mistake. I actually need to keep the white space within the values. So I need to be able to have `{%- assign x = "a a, b b, c c" -%}` output `a a,b b,c c`

Comment: I see ! Then just use  | replace: "," , " "

Comment: It's actually `{{ x | replace: ", ", "," }}`. That gives me the desired output of `a a,b b,c c`.

Comment: it really depends on your needs just use the appropiate filter.